# Can i set a rxjs timer in a subscribe method in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

```
    myfunction$.subscribe(res=>{
this.myfunc2()
this.myfunc3()
this.loading=false // I want to this line run a little bit later

})
```

How can I achive that adding a delay to the 3.line? If I give a timer in the pipe it will make delay to the all 3 thing or am i wrong? Settimeout would be work may be but I want to do it in reactive way

Comment: setTimeout would be the way to go here, but feels like a code smell. Would I be correct in saying you actually want to set `this.loading=false` when `myFunc2()` and `myFunc3()` have finished executing (and llikely  there is something asynchronous in one of them which means `this.loading=false` is being set "early"). If so you really want to wait for the completion of those functions. If that is correct, please show the contents of those functions and we can help advise further

Answer (score 2):

```
myfunction$.pipe(
  tap(res => {
    this.myfunc2();
    this.myfunc3();
  }),
  delay(1000), // or whatever time you want
).subscribe(() => this.loading=false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want two effects to happen. So I'd do this:

```
const sharedMyFunction$ = myFunction$.pipe(
  shareReplay(1) // or just share() if my myFunction$ is asynchronous.
);

sharedMyFunction$.subscribe(res=>{
  this.myfunc2()
  this.myfunc3()
})

sharedMyFunction$.pipe(
  take(1),
  delay(1000)
).subscribe(res=> {
  this.loading = false;
})
```